# What to do when done using POSIX QUEUE

Tags: c, multithreading, message-queue

I am using mqueue.h to use POSIX message queue to communicate between threads (for school project demonstration).

When I am done with my two pthreads using the queue and want to close the message queue, what should I do?

1. Do mq_unlink and mq_close from both threads
2. Do mq_unlink and mq_close from one thread
3. Only do mq_unlink from one thread
4. Only do mq_unlink from two threads
5. Only do mq_close from one thread
6. Only do mq_close from two threads

Edit (because of): "Closed. This question needs details or clarity"

I am using a POSIX message queue defined in mqueue.h (C) to send messages between threads. This is similar to interprocess communication with a message queue. I could communicate using the shared memory but that is not what I want to do. I have created, opened, sent and received messages between threads successfully but need to know what to do when done. I have found mq_close and mq_unlink but have not found information about how they should be used and from where. That is what I am asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mq_overview](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html) - overview of POSIX message queues.

Similar like dealing with files.

Call `mq_close` on each `mq_open`.

> When a process has finished using the queue, it closes it using `mq_close`(3), and when the queue is no longer required, it can be deleted using `mq_unlink`(3).

Call once `mq_unlink` optionally.

> POSIX message queues have kernel persistence: if not removed by `mq_unlink`(3), a message queue will exist until the system is shut down.
>
> `mq_unlink()` removes the specified message queue name.  The message queue name is removed immediately.  The queue itself is destroyed once any other processes that have the queue open close their descriptors referring to the queue.

Comment: Making the unlink "optional" seems like a good way to have a leak.

Comment: Also, this answer seems to deal with *processes* rather than threads

Comment: @NateEldredge Do you consider created files as leaks?

Comment: @S.M.: If you create temporary files and don't delete them when they're no longer needed, then yes, that's a resource leak too.

Comment: @NateEldredge So, to delete or not is an option, depending on app requirements, right?